# HP Proliant ML350 G5 dont runs at 48GB RAM

Tags: memory

Before I had 28GB of RAM in this configuration:

```
DIMM 1A : 2048 MB 667 MHz
DIMM 2B : 4096 MB 667 MHz
DIMM 3C : 4096 MB 667 MHz 
DIMM 4D : 4096 MB 667 MHz 
DIMM 5A : 2048 MB 667 MHz
DIMM 6B : 4096 MB 667 MHz
DIMM 7C : 4096 MB 667 MHz 
DIMM 8D : 4096 MB 667 MHz
```

Everything worked fine.

Now I ordered 4x 8GB Sticks which are PC2-5300F ECC RAMs, same as the others.

I put them in following:

```
1A: 8GB
2B: 8GB
3C: 4GB
4D: 4GB
5A: 8GB
6B: 8GB
7C: 4GB
8D: 4GB
```

But on Startup it only shows 32GB of RAM.
In Bios it says 49XXXMB installed (Dont remeber correct value)
HP ILO says following:

```
DIMM 1A : 8192 MB 667 MHz
DIMM 2B : 8192 MB 667 MHz 
DIMM 3C : 4096 MB 667 MHz 
DIMM 4D : 4096 MB 667 MHz
DIMM 5A : 8192 MB 667 MHz
DIMM 6B : 8192 MB 667 MHz
DIMM 7C : 4096 MB 667 MHz 
DIMM 8D : 4096 MB 667 MHz
```

After that i replaced 2x 4GB RAMs with 2x 2GB RAMs, Startup shows 32GB, in BIOS 44GB.

I switched them much times around and all time only 32GB.

One time i only started with 4x 8GB Sticks, show 32GB Ram and works.

So whats the problem?
Is it because of different Memory Types?
Should I order new 4x 8GB Sticks so I have 64GB RAM with 8x 8GB sticks?

I installed newest BIOS already.

I have 2x Xeon E5420 CPUs.

Comment: What happens when you've got more than 32G installed? Does the OS boot at all?

Comment: Yes, it will boot. But only shows 32GB. If i only run with 4x 8GB it works too. Currently im trying to install HP Proliant Service Care Pack, hopefully this helps. EDIT: If i enable ECC Support with online spare it will show usuable 32GB and 8GB for online spare. If i do the same thing with only 32GB installed, it will use 8GB for spare and shows 24GB usuable.

Comment: What operating system is this?

Comment: ESXI 5.5, but Startup screen of HP shows 32GB, only BIOS shows total 48GB memory

Comment: 5.5's not supported on G5 - end of conversation sorry

Comment: I know its not supported, but this dont matters, the Server itself dont recognizes the Memory, not the OS. Startup screen detects 32GB and BIOS schows "configured memory 48GB"

Answer (score 6):

HP Quickspec for this server (https://www.hpe.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04284193.pdf) says that it will only take a maximum of 32GB.

Comment: Yep, good answer Paul - @mrcash you need to rip out those 8GB modules, that server never accepted them - also that server went end-of-service-life years ago, serverfault's for supportable systems sorry.

Comment: HP says it accepts max 64GB http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c00726306&sp4ts.oid=1121586 and on ebay they get selled with 64gb of ram. "Maximum memory capacities for all AMP modes will increase with the availability of 4 GB and 8 GB FBDIMMs, including a maximum of 64 GB in Advanced ECC mode."